# Powershell script failing on "ConvertToDateTime"

Tags: powershell

I have the following script:

```
$ExcludedUsers = ”Public”, ”Administrator”, ”mdtadmin”
$LocalProfiles = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_UserProfile | Where { (!$_.Special) -and (!$_.Loaded) -and ($_.ConvertToDateTime($_.LastUseTime) -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-60)) }

foreach ($LocalProfile in $LocalProfiles) 
{
    if (!($ExcludedUsers -like $LocalProfile.LocalPath.Replace(“C:\Users\”, ””))) 
    {
        $LocalProfile | Remove-WmiObject
        Write-host $LocalProfile.LocalPath, “profile deleted” -ForegroundColor Magenta
    }
}
```

However, it seems to fail on the 2nd line, returning the following error:

```
Stopped at: [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($args[0])
```

It has something to do with the `ConvertToDateTime` cmdlet - complaining that it cannot convert from null. I'm new to Powershell script language, so I'm at a bit of a loss as to what is happening here.

EDIT: Here is the full error - It's now saying that the method doesn't even exist? I have also switched from `Get-WMIObject` to `Get-CimInstance`

```
Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance] does not contain a method named 'ConvertToDateTime'.
At C:\Users\[...]\Delete Profile.ps1:3 char:69
+ ... e | Where { (!$_.Special) -and (!$_.Loaded) -and ($_.ConvertToDateTim ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ConvertToDateTime:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Comment: Why does you title says "**Python** script"?

Comment: You should not use `Get-WmiObject` anymore since it is deprecated. Use `Get-CimInstance` instead. This would make your task way easier in this case because it's returning an object of type `[DateTime]` instead of `[String]` ;-)

Comment: Have you included the *full* error message? It doesn’t mention mull values, so I’m guessing there’s more error output than what you’ve posted?

Comment: What is the result of `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()`? Is it possible that you could upgrade to a modern day PowerShell Core? https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell Then you could use `Get-CimInstance`. Then you would get `InvalidOperation: Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance] does not contain a method named 'ConvertToDateTime'.`

Comment: @lit An upgrade is not necessary. `Get-CimInstance` is available in version 5.1 as well. It's been actually available since version 3.0.

Comment: Have you actually read the comments? Did you try unsing `Get-CimInstance`? You can compare its return property `LastUseTime` directly to a `[DateTime]` value without the need for converting!!  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Answer (score 0):

How about updating from Wmi to Cim:

```
$ExcludedUsers = "Public", "Administrator", "mdtadmin"
$LocalProfiles = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_UserProfile | Where-Object { (!$_.Special) -and (!$_.Loaded) -and ($_.ConvertFromDateTime($_.LastUseTime) -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-60)) }

foreach ($LocalProfile in $LocalProfiles) 
{
    if (!($ExcludedUsers -like $LocalProfile.LocalPath.Replace("C:\Users\", ""))) 
    {
        $LocalProfile | Remove-CimInstance
        Write-Host "$($LocalProfile.LocalPath) profile deleted" -ForegroundColor Magenta
    }
}
```

Changed the method call from ConvertToDateTime to ConvertFromDateTime for the LastUseTime property of the CimInstance object. This should resolve the method not found error.

Updated the Write-Host statement to use double quotes (") to correctly include the value of $LocalProfile.LocalPath in the output.