# Script does not capture/populate collection

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script to delete user profiles older than (x) days and so far I've [overcome one issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77124820/powershell-script-failing-on-converttodatetime) only to run into a new one.

What I have so far is:

```
$ExcludedUsers = ”Public”, ”Administrator”, ”mdtadmin”

$LocalProfiles = Get-CimInstance -class Win32_UserProfile | Where { (!$_.Special) -and (!$_.Loaded) -and ($_.LastUseTime) -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-60) }

foreach ($LocalProfile in $LocalProfiles) {

    if (!($ExcludedUsers -like $LocalProfile.LocalPath.Replace(“C:\Users\”, ””))) {

        $LocalProfile | Remove-WmiObject

        Write-host $LocalProfile.LocalPath, “profile deleted” -ForegroundColor Magenta

    }

}
```

I've stepped thorugh it using the Powershell ISE, and it runs through the second line multiple times, for each profile, but then when it hits the `foreach` loop, it then jumps out immediately, I assume because the collection is empty.

I have different time periods in the `AddDays` step to accommodate for more/less profiles, but it always returns nothing. I know for a fact that I have at least 2 on my machine that are definitely older than 60 days, and more if I reduce the amount.

It however just does not produce any errors, it simply just immediately steps out of the loop. What am I not doing to properly populate the `$LocalProfiles` collection?

I am using v. 5.1.19041.3031 of Powershell, if that helps.

---

EDIT:

I found that changing the value of `AddDays` to positive (i.e., `AddDays(x)` instead of `AddDays(-x)`) actually captured the profiles. However now it is catching on the `Remove-WmiObject` line instead, returning the following error:

```
Remove-WmiObject : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take 
pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At C:\Users\BHA\OneDrive - The Cathedral School of St Anne & St James\Downloads\Delete Profile.ps1:9 char:25
+         $LocalProfile | Remove-WmiObject
+                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Win32_UserProfi...55-96889511...):PSObject) [Remove-WmiObject], ParameterBindingExce 
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveWmiObject
```

Comment: That just means your filter criteria wasn't met. I'd start by ensuring there is any profiles with less than 60 days of use time first: `Get-CimInstance Win32_UserProfile | ` ? { $_.LastUseTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(4) }` then, confirm those profiles have the rest of the properties you're trying to filter by such as `False` for the `Loaded` property.

Comment: on a separate note, your conditional statement should really be: `if (($LocalProfile.LocalPath | Split-Path -Leaf) -notin $ExcludedUsers) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks for that - I actually realised I should be using a positive number instead of taking away (60 instead of -60) however now it's returning an actual error... will update the question

Comment: if you want to grab profiles older than 60 days, `-lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-60)` is the correct arguments to use.

Comment: Well that doesn't make sense then... why is the opposite working?

Comment: Working in the sense of it finding profiles less than 2 months from now? it should find all of them. The error you're getting is because you're attempting to pass an object of type `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimInstance` to `Remove-WMIObject` that accepts objects of type `System.Management.ManagementObject`. Fancy words for, use the same *noun* ending cmdlets with one another. `Remove-CIMInstance` is what you're after.

Comment: `Get-CimInstance Win32_UserProfile | ? { $_.LastUseTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-60) }`, if this command doesn't return anything, it just means there are no profiles older than 60 days

Comment: OK yeah I thought the Wmi and Cim might clash... that worked when I add days, but even if I only take away 1 day, it still doesn't catch any? And I know for a fact that at least one profile I have is over 12 months old

Comment: If you do have a profile in fact that is older than 12 months old, `Get-CimInstance Win32_UserProfile | ? { $_.LastUseTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-60) }` should return it. If nothing is returned, that means there has been no profile that has not been in use (*in accordance with the `LastUseTime` property*) for more than 60 consecutive days.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255337/discussion-between-abraham-zinala-and-ben).